# regex lookahead matching keyword and excluding a specific pattern ahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want regex to match the whole sentence after **any** `ERROR` (including ERROR itself) except when `ERROR` is followed by `MO already exists`. So for example in below I want the **whole** lines of 1,2,3,4 but **nothing** from line 5.

```
ERROR  
we have an ERROR here da da da  
ERROR Parent MO not found  
ERROR anything else is here  
ERROR MO already exists
```

I have tried below lookahead in regex to match the desired pattern but not fully achieved what I wanted.
`ERROR (?!MO already exist)`
What modification do I need?

Comment: try adding space before MO like this `ERROR(?!\sMO\salready\sexists) `

Comment: Thank you, that is one step ahead, but this only matched the ERROR itself, I want the whole sentence after ERROR to be matched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples could you please try following. Onlie demo [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6QeqZ/1)

```
ERROR\s+(?!MO already exist).*$
```

***Explanation:*** Looking for ERROR space(s) then checking negative look ahead to make sure it doesn't have `MO already exist` and matching everything till end of line here.

NOTE: OR in case you can have more than one spaces between `MO already exists` then try following.

```
ERROR\s+(?!MO\s+already\s+exist).*$
```